# Hold out tensorflow 1.4 new dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

With the new dataset object, is there a way to divide a dataset into training and test dataset, according to a certain ratio, to get an hold out? and a k-fold cross validation?

In my case i wrote all data in only one TFRecord file and then i imported it with tf.data.TFRecordDataset.

Now, for hold out i'd like a way to split this given dataset in two datasets with a ratio. I solved this with data.take() and data.skip() but for ratio i need dataset's lenght, it's not graceful.

```
def split_dataset(dataset, ratio, n):
 count_train = (n*ratio)//100
 train = dataset.take(count_train)
 test = dataset.skip(count_train)
 return train,test

filenames = ["dataset_breast.tfrecords"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

train_dataset, test_dataset = split_dataset(dataset, 80, 3360)
```

While for k-fold, i find only solution with scikit workaround on the dataset, before tf.data.TFRecordDataset importing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any feature like what you're describing. There are, of course, ways to achieve the functionality you're after. Here's two:

### "Source" Placeholder

This one comes straight from the API [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_tfrecord_data). Though it is originally intended for `TFRecordDataset`, I imagine it could be adapted to other types. I'll copy/paste from the link:

```
filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(...)  # Parse the record into tensors.
dataset = dataset.repeat()  # Repeat the input indefinitely.
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

# You can feed the initializer with the appropriate filenames for the current
# phase of execution, e.g. training vs. validation.

# Initialize `iterator` with training data.
training_filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={filenames: training_filenames})

# Initialize `iterator` with validation data.
validation_filenames = ["/var/data/validation1.tfrecord", ...]
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={filenames: validation_filenames})
```

A little discussion: This works with just one training tfrecord and one validation tfrecord, too. So, you could split your data using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` *before* writing the TFRecords. Write one TFRecord dedicated to training data, one dedicated to validation data. With `sklearn`, you can specify a ratio (or an absolute number).

### Two Datasets

Exactly like the name says, forget the `filenames = tf.placeholder`. Just create two iterators, one for testing and one for training. I usually use TFRecords, but you're free to try another type of dataset. Typically, I put the `get_next` calls into a `tf.cond` on a boolean `tf.placeholder`. If you're especially interested in this method, I could provide a MWE. But, the source placeholder seems to be the preferred method (seeing as it's in the docs...).

Comment: Saddly, i had a different approch. In my case i wrote all data in only one TFRecord file and then i imported it with tf.data.TFRecordDataset. Now, i'd like a way to split this given dataset in two datasets with a ratio, without your scikit pre-processing. i solved this with data.take() and data.skip() but for ratio i need dataset's lenght.

Comment: @AlessandroPagliaro Admittedly, one TFR seems like the obvious way to manage a dataset. Makes more sense than rewriting for every new random split. I would add that restriction to your question. Meanwhile I'll look into it.